# Error encountered when running 'hokuyo_node' after installing it in ROS Kinetic from: "how-to-install-hokuyo_nodeurg_node-on-kinetic" question

Tags: hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i install hokuyo_node in kinetic from this link https://answers.ros.org/question/243232/how-to-install-hokuyo_nodeurg_node-on-kinetic/
but when i try to run the node : rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node
i get this error :slight_smile:
[ERROR] [1511453614.949279898]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.
Failed to open port: /dev/ttyACM0. No such file or directory (errno = 2). The requested port does not exist. Is the hokuyo connected? Was the port name misspelled? (in hokuyo::laser::open) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting
and when i try this : ls /dev/ttyACM*
or this : ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
i get No such file or directory

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276568/i-install-hokuyo_node-in-kinetic-from-this-link-https://answers.ros.org/question/243232/how-to-install-hokuyo_nodeurg_node-on-kinetic/-but-when-i-try-to-run-the-node-:-rosrun-hokuyo_node-hokuyo_node-i--get-error/) by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2017-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your sensor does not appear to be pluggedin, or the port is not configured currectly. See the troubleshooting guide: http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting and if you don't see anything there please edit your question with the debugging outputs of all those commands.

Also search for releated questions on this site. I find a bunch of [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aanswers.ros.org+hokuyo+no+such+device&oq=site%3Aanswers.ros.org+hokuyo+no+such+device&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.10981j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdelkrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/29601/abdelkrim/) on 2017-11-27**:
thank you so much
i have changed the cable usb  it works perfectly now thanks